# google.script.run not working when other users submit a comment

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The functionality listed below executes properly when I submit content back to the server through google.script.run however it does not work for my coworkers in the same file. These coworkers are on the same domain and have edit access to the spreadsheet and are able to load the first portion of the feature, the rough-sketch modal, from the template I built (html shown below).

Our experiences seem to diverge when they hit the "Submit" button - their client should be calling `google.script.run.userSubmissions`. On the back-end executions view, however, I do not receive any indication that their client side script is properly calling the `userSubmission` function - shown below I would expect it to show up at the top, line item 3 is when I performed the same action and my client called google.script.run as expected. Also, I cannot seem to see any errors being reported of any kind.

[image: Executions List showing the function was not called when a different user hit the submit button]

Full html being presented in a floating modal window:

- Note: I have 3 scriptlets printing in the function call and have verified that these are working properly in my co-workers clients

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Provide Comment</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Provide comment for content item #</h3>
    <div>
      <span>Title</span>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label style="display: block;" for="commentInput">Comment:</label>
      <textarea
        id="userComment"
        style="display: block; margin: 1em 0 1em 0; width: 99%;"
        name="commentInput"
        rows="10"
        placeholder="Please provide your comment here..."
      ></textarea>
      <button style="float: right;" onclick="submitComment()">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
    <script>
      function submitComment() {
        let comment = document.getElementById("userComment").value;

        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(closeModal)
          .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
          .userSubmission(
            comment,
            "comment",
            parseInt(<?= contentIDColumn; ?>),
            parseInt(<?= eventContentID; ?>),
            parseInt(<?= statusColumn; ?>)
          );

        function closeModal() {
          google.script.host.close();
        }
        function onFailure(error) {
          console.log(error);
          let message = "There was an error processing that form. Perhaps try again?"
          document.getElementById("errorMessage").textContent = message;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: What are your webapp settings? Who has access to the app and who does the app execute as?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Anyone within my domain has access to the webapp and it is currently executing as me

Comment: There should be a error logged in thier browser console. You need to quote it in your question.

Comment: @TheMaster This is the only error they received in their console: "Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/rpc:shindig_random.js?onload=init' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-TIOoFqbkxnKHbOy4Q8uWwA' 'unsafe-inline' 'strict-dynamic' https: http: 'unsafe-eval'". 'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based whitelisting is disabled. Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback."

Comment: try clearing cache, ask them to logout all accounts and login again with one account only. See if there are any more errors in the console and whether the error only comes when they hit  submit button